# Did Maester Luwin really believe that sorcery and magic is no more?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Since Bran became a cripple in *Game of Thrones* and began seeing the three-eyed raven in his dreams, Maester Luwin insisted on it being just dreams and nothing much.

We can believe that an old knowledgeable man wouldn't want to worry a kid about these things even if he knows those are really, he could probably be thinking that it was just a dream, but it happened not just once and Maester Luwin wanted Bran to believe that these are nothing but just dreams. He even told Bran that he tried his hand at spells like many Maesters do but failed.

Did Maester Luwin really think that Bran's dreams were nothing but just coincidences, or he wanted to keep these things away from him to protect him, as he might have sensed that it could possibly be dangerous for him to discover and use his powers?

As a Maester, he might be more knowledgeable in this field than a general person, assuming that he had no idea about it is quite difficult.

Comment: Well, magic was mostly gone and only recently started to grow in power with return of dragons.

Answer (score 11):

We are never privy to the inner thoughts of Maester Luwin as he was never in the POV seat. However, we *do* know from the books that he did once believe in magic. He is one of the few Maesters who have troubled themselves to acquire a Valyrian steel link in their Maester chain, symbolizing that he had done studies in magic and the occult. He even admitted to Bran that he tried his hand at casting some magic spells, an effort that failed miserably. Maester Luwin eventually abandoned the study of magic, believing it to be useless and that magic was gone. Luwin had this to say to Bran about magic:

> Perhaps magic was once a mighty force in the world, but no longer. What little remains is no more than the wisp of smoke that lingers in the air after a great fire has burned out, and even that is fading. Valyria was the last ember, and Valyria is gone.

This leads me to believe that Luwin is sincere when he says that he believes that magic is no more.

Comment: Sincere that ***he believes***.